# Eclipse Error '!'

Tags: android, eclipse

Dumb question and i cannot seem to find it with google. However, my android app doesn't have a syntax error so there are no [X] anywhere but the application dir has a red ! on it and it says there's an error and fails to run. Can anyone tell me what this error indicates?

Comment: Check the "error" view to get more details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes this works:
close your project : right click on project -> Close Project, 
Restart eclipse, 
clean projects : Project -> Clean... -> Clean All

Comment: Thanks! This fixed it but i wonder what the under lining issue is.

Answer (score 2):

Clean your project, Project -> Clean... -> Clean Projects.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the listed steps:

**Step 1:** Right Click on project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path

**Step 2:** remove the library which is having red `x` sign.

**Step 3:** Click ok and clean up your project,it is ready to run.

Comment: @jcaruso: Yeah,I know.and FYI `!` will be appeared without any `x` sign whenever you delete any library from `libs` folder but forget to remove it from build path.

Comment: ok, see that makes since now. Thanks for clarifying. I'll remember that, however in this instance there it had nothing to do with lib's. Just was acting funny so doing what they did in the answer fixed it. FYI: thanks, everyone on here is so extremely helpful and always jumping to fix anything you come up with! KEEP UP THE GOOD WORK!